# Cron job schedule time changes automatically

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have a cron job `*/2 * * * *` in the cpanel , after several hours this changes automatically to `*/17 * * * *`, or `*/19 * * * *` or `*/15 * * * *`. I noticed this change many days. I was waiting for the task to complete in 2 minutes, several tasks have been completed, but after several hours i saw it isn't working, so I checked the cron jobs in cpanel and I saw the `*/2` was changed to `*/19 * * * *`.

It's not a good for every one because its not possible for check cron jobs every day.

Comment: I have faced same issue,still didn't find any solution

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Vishwakarma .. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: HI @Droymanz....... I have find the solution it is problem for the hosting services.............

Comment: Can you suggest me solution for this please ?

Comment: Hi @VivekPipaliya...... This is problem from server side. you need to contact host provider and enhance the services of server

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a cron job rescheduling initiated by hosting provider to evenly distribute server loads throughput (I am thinking of hosting service because you mentioned cpanel). You should contact your hosting support to discuss it.

Comment: As per my understanding you are using shared server where you can't set cron time less than 15 minutes otherwise it will change.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on this same problem, then I talked to my hosting providers and they says, 'If you set the timings to every 15 minutes, It won't be changed. If you set anything under 15 minutes it leads to changes in timings. VPS Cron job has lower limits